# Sitecore content gone in web DB after publish

Tags: sitecore

I've been happily developing away on a Sitecore project for the last couple of months. This evening I did what I have done 100 times, smart published the entire site so that I could view it from the web DB as an end user.

When I navigated to the site I discovered that all of my content is gone. All rendering elements are there, but anything in the /sitecore/content tree is missing on the page. Gone. Empty. Nada.

Everything looks fine when I'm logged in and viewing in Page Editor.

I've done several smart publishes and still the same. I was going to try a republish of everything, but after reading the warning dialog I thought I'd wait until I understand what happened.

This is a pretty disconcerting thing. Any one have any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the log files to make sure nothing is warning you in there? I'm am assuming you switched to the web db in the Sitecore interface and checked the content tree? Doing a full republish will not be a problem, it may be a little time consuming depending on how many items you have. Check publish state as Pavan has stated, also check that something is not stuck in workflow waiting for approval.

Answer (score 0):

Check your root or home item , make sure it is in publishable state and check if it published. If the root item is gone your will not see anything on the site.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you will want to check on your root node where content is missing:

1. **Workflow state:** If there is only one version, but the workflow state was changed to a non-final version manually, it will not be published.
2. **Publishing Restrictions Publishable state:** If the 'Publishable' checkbox has been disabled for any item or version, that item/version will not publish.
3. **Publishing Restrictions by Date:** If a date-based publishing restriction has been applied to the item or versions, the item may have been removed because it is no longer in a publishable date range.

Answer (score 0):

If this is on Sitecore 7.2, i think there is a bug where content items just disappear:
http://maxslabyak.com/sitecore/3-new-sitecore-v7-2-bugs-need-know-go-live/

To Fix it, set this setting **Publishing.PublishEmptyItems** to **true**

Hope this helps